# How can I display different products from an array in each custom cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitableview

I need to display three or less products from an array in every custom cell of a tableview, I putted three image views and three labels in each cell to show the products. This is my TableviewDataSource Code.

```
 // MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return products.count / 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

let sectionIndex = indexPath.section

    if (sectionIndex + index + 2) <= products.count && (sectionIndex + index + 1) <= products.count && currentUser != nil {

        cell.product1 = self.products[sectionIndex + index]
        cell.product2 = self.products[sectionIndex + index + 1]
        cell.product3 = self.products[sectionIndex + index + 2]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        index += 2

    }

    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

And this is my TableviewCell Code.

protocol CustomCell : class {
    func accessToProduct(product: Product)
    func performSegueToProduct()
}

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var image1 : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image2 : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image3 : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

weak var delegate: CustomCell?


var product1: Product! {
    didSet {
        updateUI1()
    }
}
var product2: Product! {
    didSet {
        updateUI2()
    }
}
var product3: Product! {
    didSet {
        updateUI3()
    }
}

var cache = SAMCache.shared()

func downloadPopularImages (product: Product, imageView: UIImageView, label: UILabel) {

    imageView.image = nil
    let productuid = product.uid
    let profileImageKey = "\(productuid)"

    if let image = cache?.object(forKey: profileImageKey) as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
    } else {

    product.downloadPopularProductImage { [weak self] (image, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            imageView.image = image
            self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profileImageKey)
        }
        }
    }
}

 // MARK: - Update the UI downloading product images and adding tapGestureRecognizer

func updateUI1() {
    downloadPopularImages(product: product1, imageView: image1, label: label1)
    label1.text = product1.name + " \(product1.subName)"
    let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.image1IsTapped))
    image1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)
}

func image1IsTapped () {

    delegate?.accessToProduct(product: product1)
    print(product1)
    delegate?.performSegueToProduct()

}

func updateUI2() {
    downloadPopularImages(product: product2, imageView: image2, label: label2)
    label2.text = product2.name + " \(product2.subName)"
    let tapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.image2IsTapped))
    image2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer2)

}

func image2IsTapped() {
    delegate?.accessToProduct(product: product2)
    delegate?.performSegueToProduct()
}


func updateUI3() {
    downloadPopularImages(product: product3, imageView: image3, label: label3)
    label3.text = product3.name + " \(product3.subName)"
    let tapGestureRecognizer3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.image3IsTapped))
    image3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer3)
}

func image3IsTapped() {
    delegate?.accessToProduct(product: product3)
    delegate?.performSegueToProduct()
}
```

}

However, if I have an array with a number of products that is not divisible by 3, does not correctly display all products. Imagine that we have 5 products, so in the first cell it will display the three first products and in the second cell it will display the two remaining products and there will be one image view and one label empties. But this doesn't happen, the code fills the above with one of the products already displayed.
I tried to use a collection view with three cells y each tableview cell but I need the cells of the uicollectionview to be fixed and not cut with the edges, so for that reason i implemented the three image views and three labels.

How can I fix this?

This is what I want:
[image: Favorite Products]

Comment: I know you said you tried using a CollectionView and chose a tableView but I'll go ahead and weigh in that you definitely should use a CollectionView for the screenshot you included. We can help you understand how to fix the problems you had with the collectionView. But trying to bend a tableview to work this way is definitely going to make your life harder. A collectionView can handle this easily.

Comment: Hi @RyanPoolos I'll appreciate if you could help me to understand how to implement the collection view to get a better code!

Comment: what type of problems were you having with the collectionView? That might be a good starting point. :)